# Tweaking the Google Maps scale bar

Tags: google-maps, scale

is there a way to move, resize, adjust or skin the default scale bar in Google Maps API? It looks like it's only possible to switch this feature on and off.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is too broad, it's a yes/no question - I'd like to know if there's an answer.

Comment: When you take a look into the documentation you'll see that there are no options you can choose, the answer should be clear: **NO**